# VBA excel - similar Controls and concatenate functions in modules vs userform?

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, controls, concatenation

I'm making a questionnaire using VBA excel using comboboxes. I have 36 comboboxes (cmb1, cmb2, cmb3 ... cmb36) and I use a For loop to populate my comboboxes from my excel sheet "Options" using this code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
For i = 1 To 36
   Controls("cmb" & i).RowSource = "Options!A1:A5"
Next i 
End sub
```

This works but i want to do something similar using modules instead (i.e. populating the comboboxes with the array from calling a function from a module, instead of initializing them in UserForm), but I'm not able to use the Controls function in modules so I have no idea how to concatenate the "cmb" and the "i" and do something similar

Any help will be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to accomplish the task:

**UserForm Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
   InitControls Me
End Sub
```

**Module Code**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub InitControls(ByVal MyForm As UserForm)
   Dim i As Integer

   For i = 1 To 36
      MyForm.Controls("cmb" & i).RowSource = "Options!A1:A5"
   Next i
End Sub
```